# How do I change the active element of the Murmur fusion rifle?

Tags: destiny

Having recently completed some of the *The Dark Below* story missions in Destiny, Eris Morn gave me a special legendary fusion rifle, the [Murmur](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Murmur).

It says that it can toggle between arc and solar damage, but I've pressed every button and combination I can think of and haven't had any success.

How do I toggle the elemental trait of the Murmur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to go into the weapon's upgrade screen and toggle it manually.  Should be unlocked right from the start.

[image: Murmur]

Answer (score 2):

Open your inventory, press Y/Triangle on the weapon, and toggle the active element on the far left as if it was an upgrade.